# jooq: How to deal with POINT MySQL datatype

Tags: mysql, jooq

I have the following table in MySQL

```
CREATE TABLE `place` (
  `ID` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `NAME` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `STREET_NUMBER` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ROUTE` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOCALITY` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADM_AREA_L1` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ADM_AREA_L2` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `COUNTRY` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `POSTAL_CODE` varchar(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `FORMATTED_ADDRESS` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `LOCATION` point DEFAULT NULL,
  `CLOSING_TIME` time DEFAULT NULL,
  `CREATION_DATE` timestamp NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

It has a field of type POINT, to make geolocation queries over that field. The Pojo generated by jooq is the following:

```
public class Place implements java.io.Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1847682719;

    private java.lang.Long     id;
    private java.lang.String   name;
    private java.lang.Integer  streetNumber;
    private java.lang.String   route;
    private java.lang.String   locality;
    private java.lang.String   admAreaL1;
    private java.lang.String   admAreaL2;
    private java.lang.String   country;
    private java.lang.String   postalCode;
    private java.lang.String   formattedAddress;
    private java.lang.Object   location;
    private java.sql.Time      closingTime;

    // getters and setters
}
```

This is the kind of queries that I want to execute:

- Inserting a new record. The sql for the POINT datatype would be:

  ```
  INSERT INTO PLACE(LOCATION) VALUES(POINT(1,1));
  ```
- Getting latitude and longitude from the POINT datatype. The sql would be:

  ```
  SELECT X(LOCATION), Y(LOCATION) FROM PLACE;
  ```
- Quering places withing a distance range. The sql would be:

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM PLACE
  WHERE ST_WITHIN(LOCATION, ENVELOPE(LINESTIRNG(
  POINT(@lon - @distance / abs(cos(radians(@lat)) * 69), @lat - (@distance / 69)),
  POINT(@lon + @distance / abs(cos(radians(@lat)) * 69), @lat + (@distance / 69))
  )))
  ORDER BY ST_DISTANCE(POINT(<lon>, <lat>), LOCATION);
  ```

Do I have to create a `CustomField` for each situation (inserting, getting latitude and longitude, quering by distance range, ordering by distance)?

In case of creating a `CustomField`. `CustomField` of what? Because the `LOCATION` field generated by jooq in `Place` table is of type `DataType<Object>`.

I have tried to execute an insert setting the `LOCATION` field and it does not compile because the `execute()` method is undefined for the `Field<Object>`.

Answer (score 0):

#### Using jOOQ 3.16

Starting with jOOQ 3.16, [#982](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/982) has been implemented and jOOQ supports [ISO/IEC 13249-3:2016](https://www.iso.org/standard/60343.html) spatial extensions out of the box. Your generated code will reference the `SQLDataType.GEOMETRY` type, for example, and you can use WKT or WKB encodeded spatial data in `org.jooq.Geometry`, the wrapper type, just like any other data type in jOOQ.

[A lot of spatial functions are already supported out of the box](https://www.jooq.org/doc/dev/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/spatial-functions/). If something is still missing, you can always resort to using [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/).

#### Using older versions of jOOQ

In older versions of jOOQ, [plain SQL templating](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/) and [custom data type bindings](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/custom-data-type-bindings/) are your only option here.